# Getting children of a List Item via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get the content of folders within a SharePoint List using the REST Graph API.

I currently am able to get the folder within the list with the following url:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site1:/sites/site2:/lists/list1/items/53`

I try to get the children of this item with the following url:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site1:/sites/site2:/lists/list1/items/53/children`

But this gives me the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'children'.",
        "innerError": {
            **snip**
        }
    }
}
```

All the documentation I find about listing a folder's content either uses drive, group, or something else in their example, not a listitem.
Because of this I have not been able to find any documentation that matches my situation.

I'm trying to list all the folders, sub-folders, and items within a SharePoint List.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'driveitem' to the url will point from the listitem to the actual driveitem.

So the final URL is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site1:/sites/site2:/lists/list1/items/53/driveitem/children
```